# Find the solution of an ODES system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $g$ be a $\pi$-periodic continuous function and $f_1 , f_2$ two $\pi$-periodic functions of class $C^1$ on $[0,\pi]$.

what is the solution for the following system?
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-f_1^{'}(x)+ a\; g(x) \cos(x)+f_2(x)=0\\
-f_2^{'}(x)- a\;g(x)\sin(x)+f_1(x)=0
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $a$ is a real constant

unfortunately I have no idea to start !

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Define $f(x) = f_1(x) + i f_2(x)$ as a complex map, find $f$ as the solution of a complex ODE. $f_1,f_2$ are then respectively the real and imaginary parts of $f$.

Comment: thanks @mathcounterexamples.ne , how we can write the complex ODE ?

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $i$ and add the second one.

Comment: ok thanks @mathcounterexamples.ne

Comment: This does not work with the current signs in front of $f_1,f_2$. You can use $f_1+f_2$ and $f_1-f_2$ to decouple the equations.