# Find the solution of ODEs sytem with periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

this question looks like the question related to my question "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3876561/find-the-solution-of-an-odes-system " and I can't find a solution for both

Let $g$ be a $\pi$-periodic continuous function and $f_1 , f_2$ two $\pi$-periodic functions of class $C^1$ on $[0,\pi]$.

what is the solution for the following system?
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-f_1^{'}(x)+ a\; g(x) \cos(x)+f_2(x)=0\\
f_2^{'}(x)+ a\;g(x)\sin(x)+f_1(x)=0
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $a$ is a real constant

thanks for any complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the $2\times 2$ system of ODEs
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
f_1'=f_2 +a g(x) \cos x,\\
f_2'=-f_1 -a g(x)\sin x.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Or setting $f=(f_1,f_2)$
$$
f'=\left(
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 &1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)f+\binom{a g(x) \cos x}{-a g(x)\sin x}
$$
General solution
$$
\binom{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}=\exp\left(\left(
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 &1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)x\right)c+\int_0^x \exp\left(\left(
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 &1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)(x-y)\right)\binom{a g(y) \cos y}{-a g(y)\sin y}dy \\ = 
\left(\begin{array}{rr} 
\cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x
\end{array}
\right)\binom{c_1}{c_2}
+\int_0^x\left(\begin{array}{rr} 
\cos (x-y) & \sin (x-y) \\ -\sin (x-y) & \cos (x-y)
\end{array}
\right)\binom{a g(y) \cos y}{-a g(y)\sin y}dy \\ =
\left(\begin{array}{rr} 
\cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x
\end{array}
\right)\binom{c_1}{c_2}+\int_0^x \binom{ag(y)\cos x}{-ag(y)\sin x}dy \\
=\binom{c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x}{-c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x}
+\binom{a\cos x\int_0^x g(y)}{-a\sin x\int_0^x g(y)}
$$

Comment: Thanks, @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis . is this solution still correct if considered $g$ is just a measurable function?

Comment: Yes if $f$ is locally $L_1$. But I such case the solution is going to be generalized in the sense of Caratheodory.

Comment: Thanks @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis

Answer (score 1):

In this case you actually can apply the complexification that was proposed for the previous question, set $f=f_1+if_2$, then the system combines to the scalar equation
$$
f'(x)-ag(x)e^{-ix}+if(x)=0.
$$
Apply the integrating factor to get
$$
(e^{ix}f(x))'=ag(x)
$$
which now can be easily integrated.

Comment: Thanks, @Lutz Lehman I was confused between the real derivative and complex derivative, if we suppose that $g$ is just measurable this solution still correct?

Comment: One may have to closer specify what a solution is, so that it remains as unique as possible. If $g$ is only measurable, then $f$ will not be continuously differentiable, so you need a weaker form of derivative and function equality. There should be no problem with complex derivatives as the independent $x$ is a real variable. The complex operations are just vector operations in a more compact formulation, but equivalent to the operations in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks @Lutz Lehmann